# Proving existence of $f\in X^{\ast}$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in M$, and $\|f\|=\frac{1}{d}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $M$ a closed subspace, and let $x_0\notin M$. Define 
>   \begin{equation*}
> d=\mathrm{dist}(x_0, M)>0.
> \end{equation*}
>   Then there exists $f\in X^{\ast}$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in M$, and $\|f\|=\frac{1}{d}$.

What kind of theorem should I apply in order to get the above result?

Edit: By Tsemo Aristide's suggestion, we should use Hahn-Banach theorem to prove the statement. However I am having trouble applying it to show $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in M$, and $\|f\|=\frac{1}{d}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the theorem of Hahn Banach.

Let $f$ be the function defined on $Vect(x_0,M)$ such that $f(x_0)=1, f(x)=0, x\in M$.

Since $d(x_0,M)=d>0$, there exists $d_n>d$ such that $lim_nd_n=d$, $x_n\in M$ such that $\|x_n-x_0\|=d_n$. We have $f({{x_0-x_n}\over{\|x_0-x_n\|}})={1\over{\|x_0-x_n\|}}={1\over d_n}$, this implies that $\|f\|\leq {1\over d}$.

For every $y\in M$, $y=cx_0+x,x\in M$, suppose $c\neq 0$, $f(y)=c$ and $\|y\|=|c|\|x_0--{1\over c}x\|\geq |c|d=|f(y)d|$ this is equivalent to $|f(y)|\leq {1\over d}\|y\|$
we deduce that $\|f\|={1\over d}$.

Hahn Banach implies that we can extend $f$ to $X$ in $g$ with $\|g\|=\|f\|$.

Comment: Thanks. By applying Hahn-Banach theorem I get that there exists a linear functional $f\in X^{\ast}$ that satisfy some quality. But I do not know how to show $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in M$ and $\|f\|=\frac{1}{d}$. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. What is $Vect(x_0, M)$ notation?

Comment: The space generated by $M$ and $x_0$.

Comment: Shouldn't $f(x_0)=1$?